# Retrive and process Ckan Data using Fiware Platform

Tags: fiware, ckan, fiware-cygnus, spagobi

I'm finishing the publishing of data in Ckan and I want to retrieve, process and visualize this data using Fiware platform. But I searched for this and  couldn't find any document showing this integration. Could anyone help me with processing and visualization of Ckan data using Fiware platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SpagoBI for data visualization and analysis](https://www.fiware.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Effective-data-visualization-and-analysis-using-SpagoBI.pdf).

[Here you can read how to integrate SpagoBI with CKAN](http://spagobi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/CKAN/README/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer i studied the two links but  in the ReadtheDoc said  i  should use Fiware identify manger to could integrate Ckan With SpagoBi but  i  ask  if there is  a way i can follow to retrieve Ckan data in SpagoBi without Fiware identify manager

Comment: I guess it is not mandatory. But, if you decide to use, in the following link there is a tutorial about the Keyrock integration with other Fiware GEs: https://pt.slideshare.net/daltoncezane/integrating-fiware-orion-keyrock-and-wilma . This can be useful for you.

Comment: I just  need to Know how retrieve Data from my Ckan GE and  process it  using SpagoBi I follow the above links  but there is  missing point i cant  catch data in Spagobi when clinking  **Ckan Data Set**  So if there is simple link about the connection steps  that  will help my much better